# Symfony2 confirm form submission

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I need to be able to do an operation on form data before it gets persisted to the database. The problem is, the operation can be risky and I need the user's consent each time.

I'd like to do this through a confirmation form (with a little message explaining what's going on), not with a Javascript confirm window.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Here is an example of a controller action method that handles the form:

```
<?php
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($myEntity)
        ->add('someField', 'integer', array('required' => true))
        // Lots and lots of fields
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // CUSTOM VALIDATION HERE

            // If invalid, must display a new confirmation form to ask user
            // if it's alright to do a somewhat risky operation that would
            // validate the form data.

            // Else, persist the data.
            $db = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $db->persist($myEntity);
            $db->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_path_to_success_page'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Preferences:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'errors' => $form->getErrors(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle), which allows you to create multi-step forms.